# Rspec: yield expectation when the block must return a value

Tags: ruby, rspec

I want to test that such a method yields the proper arg:

```
class A
  def meth
    name = 'test'
    name = yield name if block_given?
    puts name + ".rb"
  end
end
```

so I wrote a test

```
  it "yields 'test'" do
    expect{ |block| A.new.meth &block  }.to yield_with_args 'test'
  end
```

but it fails since `name + .rb` raises an error as the block returns `nil`.

How can I test that the method is yielded and not get the subsequent error?

Appreciated.

Comment: where are you passing an actual block to the method? Right now all I can see is a local variable called 'block' in the expectation

Comment: That is the standard way of providing a block in RSpec. RSpec builds the block for you

Comment: yes... and no. Yes, you are building a block... and you are passing it `expect` not to the method that is taking the block. To that method, you are passing a *variable* suggestively-named `block`

Comment: now.. perhaps I could be wrong... but I'd be trying to write this as something like: `expect{ A.new.meth{|a| 'test'} }.to yield_with_args 'test'`

Comment: No and no. :) First, RSpec do give block as a block, you can check that out by setting a breakpoint or whatever test you want to see. But if you provide another block to the method called, RSpec complains since you are not using the block it generate and hence can't track yielding.

Comment: fair enough. You can, however, test it yourself that way first and see if it works that way, before using rspecs block-matching magic... sometimes attacking the problem in a different way will make the error obvious... thus trying it without the "yield_with_args" but just checking the return-value etc.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, RSpec (still) doesn't provide support for scenarios where the block must return some non-nil value lest the tested method crashes.

We can help ourselves by wrapping RSpec's test block with a Proc which passes down all arguments and at the end returns the desired value.

Please note the `probe.to_proc` call - we can't do simply `with_return_value(probe, 'return this')`, as the test probe yielded by `expect` is not a Proc (or some other object understanding `#call`) itself, but an instance of `RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::YieldProbe`. RSpec relies on [the way how Ruby deals with `&arguments` which are neither a block, nor a Proc](https://medium.com/@amliving/rubys-unary-operator-a93d36d3cd8b).

```
def with_return_value(callable, value)
  proc do |*args|
    callable.call(*args)
    value
  end
end

it "yields 'test'" do
  expect {|probe| A.new.meth(&with_return_value(probe.to_proc, 'return this')) }.to yield_with_args 'test'
end
```

Obvious downside of this approach is test readability. It takes quite some effort to decipher what the test is doing and why. Next step would be defining a custom yield matcher encapsulating the details.